# Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined with gem nested_form_fields gem

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm using `gem 'nested_form_fields'`, but when i click on `remove` it gives me error in browser console

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
>   also it doesn't work as accepted to add or remove nested attributes.

model: -

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :photos
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos, allow_destroy: true
end
```

controller: -

```
  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.photos.build if @user.photos.none?
  end
```

view: - `new.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/errors', object: @user %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control'%>
  </div>
   <%=f.nested_fields_for :photos do |photo|%>
    <%=photo.remove_nested_fields_link 'Remove'%>
    <%=photo.file_field :attachment%>
    <%=photo.add_nested_fields_link :photos, 'Next Photo'%>
   <%end%>
  <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

`application.js.erb` :-

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require nested_form_fields
//= require jquery-ui
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

kindly help me out.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think may be it is because of these line of code

```
<%=photo.add_nested_fields_link :photos, 'Next Photo'%>
```

remove_nested_fields_link needs to be called within the nested_fields_for call and add_nested_fields_link outside of it via the parent builder.

so it should be

```
<%= f.add_nested_fields_link :photos, 'Next Photo'%>
```

So code look like

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/errors', object: @user %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control'%>
  </div>
   <%=f.nested_fields_for :photos do |photo|%>
    <%=photo.remove_nested_fields_link 'Remove'%>
    <%=photo.file_field :attachment%>
   <%end%>
   <%=f.add_nested_fields_link :photos, 'Next Photo'%>
  <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: hmm i'm so dumb, as it written on document. anyway thanks for your help.